# Responsive display of words in datatable mobile view

Tags: html, jquery, css, datatables

I have the below code.

The problem is that when the text is wide on mobile some words get cut off on right side.

So I want if the words don't fit to mobile view, then words should split like this

Mobile view

```
details
Kings don home page 8082 eazy
me go do far fu ez1
```

i want to fit words in mobile view, if word is long then it split to next line

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>Datatable</title>

  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.11.3/css/jquery.dataTables.min.css">

  <script type="text/javascript" src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.js"></script>
  <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-EVSTQN3/azprG1Anm3QDgpJLIm9Nao0Yz1ztcQTwFspd3yD65VohhpuuCOmLASjC" crossorigin="anonymous">
  <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.11.3/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>

  <script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
      $('#dtab').DataTable();


    });
  </script>
</head>

<body>

  <div class="container mt-5">
    <table id="dtab" class="display" style="width:100%">
      <thead>
        <tr>
          <th>details</th>

        </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
        <tr>
          <td>Kings don home page 8082 eazy me go do far fu ez1</td>

        </tr>

      </tbody>
    </table>
  </div>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: When I run the code, I have to use a very narrow definition of "mobile" to get it to wrap even the last word... Please [edit] your question to provide a definition of the screen width you are using to define mobile.

Comment: Its going to behave in that manner, even if the mobile device is in landscape orientation. Why? Because the screen is smaller

Comment: @Richie, so how can i split words to next line if the screen is smaller

Comment: @tomlee why would you need to do so? AFAIK, there isn't a way to split the words into the next line

Comment: Please [edit] your question and code to show a [mre] of the issue. Currently it does not. Making strings split over long lines is a matter of using CSS's [`white-space: wrap`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/white-space) and [`word-break: break-word`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/word-break), depending on what exactly you need.

Comment: @HereticMonkey,   Making strings split over long lines is a matter of using CSS's white-space: wrap and word-break: break-word, depending on what exactly you need., thats wat i need when page opened in mobile and the string are long

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.